# Questions for Apple services not related to Apple software

Tags: discussion, support, site-scope

Is it on-topic asking about a login problem to an Apple web site that asks for the Apple ID, when the login is done from Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. It applies only to a small subset* of people (those using IE). Besides, that question is really better-suited for Apple's feedback forms. We can't fix their web forms!

*A small subset in an Apple Q&A environment.